# Can classes in ZFC be identified with logical predicates A(x)?

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory

I was wondering whether any class in ZFC can be identified with a logical predicate A(x) about sets.

Is that true?

I have read in Wikipedia that 'class' is an informal notion in ZFC. In that case, since category theory uses 'classes' from the very beginning, is category theory something informal?

Comment: I think the term *class* is being used in disparate ways here.  Properly ZFC does not have a primitive notion of *class* apart from its primitive notion of *set*.  However NBG is an inessential extension that provides *proper classes*, that are not sets.  Sets can be members of classes, but proper classes cannot be members of classes.

Comment: Levy's book *Basic Set Theory* (which was written as a graduate level text) has a detailed discussion of how to represent classes in ZFC-style theories using predicates.

Comment: You can identify classes with predicates, yes, as long as you allow the use of (set) parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that in ZFC everything is a set and hence it cannot "talk" about classes, dos not make the notion informal. For one there are alternative set theories that also formalize classes. And on the other hand, yes, you may identify classes with predicates. Thus the class of objects of **Set** is simply the class of all sets, i.e., to test if $x$ is an object of **Set** we test whether $x=x$ holds or the like.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I explicitly mentioned ZFC, since most mathematicians work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Some, but not all classes are usually defined as definite conditions (the set theorist's talk for what you call 'predicates'). This definition yields an unrestricted comprehension schema for classes

> For every definite condition $P(x)$ there is a class A s.t. $\forall y(y\in A \Leftrightarrow P(y))$

To see how this definition works let's assume we have a well-defined collection of definite conditions (for example, take $x=y, x \in y, set(x)$ as basic conditions and close the collection under the usual logical operations). As a matter of definition let  $x \in P \Leftrightarrow P(x)$, where $P$ is a definite condition. Let a condition $P$ be coextensive with a set $A$ ($P =_e A$), if $\forall x(P(x) \Leftrightarrow x \in A)$. By the axiom of extensionality it's obvious that each condition is coextensive with at most one set.

Now, for some condition $P$ the class $\lbrack x : P(x) \rbrack$ can be defined as follows: If $P =_e A$, for some set $A$ we let $\lbrack x : P(x) \rbrack = A$; otherwise we let $ \lbrack x : P(x) \rbrack = P$